# 1 Timothy 3:7, what is the meaning of "reproach and snare of the Devil"?

Tags: revelation, 1-timothy

1 Timothy 3:7 (DRB):

> Moreover he must have a good testimony of them who are without: lest he fall into reproach and the snare of the devil.

What is the meaning of "lest he fall into reproach and the snare of the devil"?

Does "reproach and snare of the devil" mean that Satan of good works?

Is there a relationship between this verse and Revelation 12:10?

Revelation 12:10 (DRB):

> And I heard a loud voice in heaven, saying: Now is come salvation, and strength, and the kingdom of our God, and the power of his Christ: because the accuser of our brethren is cast forth, who accused them before our God day and night.

Comment: NIV: "He must also have a good reputation with outsiders, so that he will not fall into disgrace and into the devil's trap."  Does this help?

Comment: +1 for the connection to _the accuser of the brethren_.

Answer (score 1):

**1 Timothy 3:7, what is the meaning of “reproach and snare of the Devil”?**

In First  Timothy chapter three, Paul sets out the qualifications for the appointment of elders and overseers in the Christian congregation, one of the requirements was.

1 Timothy  (NET Bible)

> 7 And he must be **well thought of by those outside the faith,** so that
>   he may not fall into disgrace and be caught by the devil’s trap.

1 Timothy 3:7  (NASB)

7 And he must have a **good reputation with those outside the church,** so that he will not fall into reproach and the snare of the devil.

One such requirement was for elders and overseers was to have a fine reputation with those outside the faith, that is non-believers.  Why?  During the first century Christians, including elders and overseers preached the good news to those outside the congregation and at the same time invited such people to attend congregation meetings.

Elders and overseers must practice what they teach in their daily lives, he should be punctual at his work, be honest, and willing to give his employer a full day's work,  be kind with his neighbors,  and his moral behavior must be beyond reproach. In others, words elders and overseers as well as all Christians had to have a fine reputation with people outside the Christian congregation.

Just imagine the reaction of a non-Christian walking into the congregation and noticing an elder that was cheating him at his work.   Having however a fine reputation with non-Christians would prevent an elder or an overseer from being exposed to a scandal and so get caught in the devil's snare.

Satan accuses servants of God, but there is no relationship between this verse and Revelation 12:10. Revelation 12:10  should be read in context with Revelation  12:7-12  in which verses we read that war broke out in heaven.  Michael and his angel battled with Satan and his angels, with Satan being hurled down to the earth.